# Синонимы веб разработчика, в том числе и на английском языке, вообщем мне нужно ...?

Tags: веб-дизайн, форум

Подскажите синонимы все возможности веб разработчика, в том числе и на английском языке, вообщем мне нужно выставить резюме, чтобы по разным запросам были выставлены резюме мои. Я занимаюсь веб разработкой сайтов. Люди ищут резюме по разным запросам, вот мне и нужно чтобы по разным запросам проходил поиск и был максимальный охват аудитории ))

Comment: перечислите языки, фреймворки, платформы, движки, типы рынка (игры, магазины и тд). глянь на поисковике требования - https://www.indeed.co.uk/m/jobs?q=web+developer&l=Manchester

Comment: Если ответ на вопрос был исчерпывающим, пожалуйста, подтвердите его как решенный.